# Why conditional loading on link is not conditional?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

If we have a link to css with media attribute like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 730px) and (max-width: 960px)" href="tablet.less"  />
```

Why is it loaded (in Chrome and Firefox, not tested all browsers) even if the width of the screen is > to 960px ?

Comment: Not the *loading* is conditional, the *application* of it is. What should happen if you suddenly resize the browser window?

Comment: You could, however, make a conditional loading with javascript. If that is a must.